# Calculating Jerk from Velocity Data

Tags: physics, kinematics

I have conducted a series of simulations implementing a path-planning algorithm in 3 dimensions and obtained an array of Linear Velocity values, from which I am attempting to calculate the Jerk. Samples were taken every 0.1 seconds, with 70 samples being obtained overall. Therefore in order to initially calculate the acceleration, I calculated (v2-v1)/t for the first value of acceleration, v3-v2/t for the second value etc. To obtain jerk I used (a2-a1)/t. However, for several points, the Jerk appears to exceed 80 m/s^3 which based on existing literature appears to be an incredibly large value!

Therefore, I wished to check that I have calculated the jerk correctly. 
E.g. Velocity at t=4.8s is -0.4785579m/s, the velocity at t = 4.9s is -0.045113680m/s and the velocity at t=5.0s is -0.2426393818m/s.

Therefore the acceleration between t=4.8s and t=4.9s is, by my theory, (-0.045113780-0.4785579)/0.1 = 4.33444234 m/s^2 and the acceleration between t=4.9s and t=5.0s is (-0.2426393818 - (-0.045113780))/0.1 = -1.975257014

Finally, the jerk should theoretically be calculated via the equation (-1.975257014-4.33444234)/0.1 = -63.096994 m/s^3.

Are my calculations correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post plots of your calculated velocity, acceleration, and jerk if possible.This may be a numerical noise issue.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: The first diffences of the velocity data is acceleration. The second differences are the quantity called Jerk. So I guess you are calculating these correctly. Do as EyeBallFrog suggests ... attach the plots (We can add them to the question) ... I have experience of analysing $3d$ accelerometer data for vehicle crashes ... calculating finite differences starts to amplify errors ... what is more crucial is sustained large acceleration for a period of time.